# My Discord bot won't send embeds from within a cog. (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send')

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I'm trying to put the commands of my Discord bot into cogs. It loads the cog just fine. But when I run the command and the bot tries to send an embed to my logging channel it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
from discord.ext import commands 
import datetime
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open(r"C:\Users\Jea\Desktop\Yuna-Discord-Bot\config.yml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    config = yaml.load(file)
    
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['Prefix'])

bot.debugchannel = config['Debug Channel ID']
bot.embed_color = discord.Color.from_rgb(
config['Embed Settings']['Color']['r'],
config['Embed Settings']['Color']['g'],
config['Embed Settings']['Color']['b'])
bot.footer = config['Embed Settings']['Footer']['Text']
bot.footerimg = config['Embed Settings']['Footer']['Icon URL']

class Testing(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot 

    @bot.command(name="ping",
             aliases=["p"],
             help="Check if the bot is online with a simple command")
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Pinged {bot.user}", color=bot.embed_color, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
        embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_footer(text=bot.footer, icon_url=bot.footerimg)
        await bot.debugchannel.send(embed=embed)
        print("Sent and embed")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
        print("Added a reaction to a message")
        await ctx.send("Pong!")
        print("Sent a message")



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Testing(bot))

print("Loaded testing cog")
```

This is the error it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Jea\Desktop\Yuna-Discord-Bot\cogs\testing.py", line 34, in ping
    await bot.debugchannel.send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Jea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'send'
```

and I know it is the line `await bot.debugchannel.send(embed=embed)`. Because when I removed it, the command worked just fine. however, I don't know what is causing it. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bot.debugchannel` just stores the id of the channel, not a `discord.TextChannel` object, and it therefore cannot be used to send messages. First, you need to get the channel itself from the id, which can be done using `ctx.guild.get_channel(<id>)`

So replace line 4 of the `ping` method with the following two lines:

```py
    debugchannel = ctx.guild.get_channel(bot.debugchannel)
    await debugchannel.send(embed=embed)
```

You might also want to consider changing the variable name of `bot.debugchannel` to `bot.debugchannel_id` or the like, to make it clearer what is going on here.